# Div is sliding after hover using css

Tags: html, css

I have created the box and when I hover on the box then that box sliding going to the right side that I don't want. I need when the user hovers on the box then display border without sliding.

Would you help me in this?

```css
.wid-30{width: 30%;}
.bg{background-color: red;}
.wid-30:hover{border-left: 10px solid yellow;}
.padding{padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="wid-30 bg padding">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies diam a dui auctor commodo. Proin nulla nibh, fermentum eu purus quis, hendrerit posuere arcu</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set `padding-left: 0` when the element is `:hover`ed-over, so that it does not move. Here's an example:

```css
.wid-30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.bg {
  background-color: red;
}

.wid-30:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid yellow;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wid-30 bg padding">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies diam a dui auctor commodo. Proin nulla nibh, fermentum eu purus quis, hendrerit posuere arcu</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `border-left: 10px solid red;` inside `.bg`

```css
.wid-30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.bg {
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 10px solid red;
}

.wid-30:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid yellow;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wid-30 bg padding">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies diam a dui auctor commodo. Proin nulla nibh, fermentum eu purus quis, hendrerit posuere arcu</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
If you set box-sizing property the dimensione of the red div doesn't change.
If you remove padding on hover you prevent the p translation.

```css
.wid-30 {
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.bg {
  background-color: red;
}

.wid-30:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid yellow;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wid-30 bg padding">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies diam a dui auctor commodo. Proin nulla nibh, fermentum eu purus quis, hendrerit posuere arcu</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good job using `box-sizing`. It seems like the most elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

Like this? I used [box-sizing: border-box](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp), set `padding-left: 0` on hover  and adjusted the width accordingly:

> border-box: The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

```css
.wid-30 {
  width: calc(30% + 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg {
  background-color: red;
}

.wid-30:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid yellow;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wid-30 bg padding">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultricies diam a dui auctor commodo. Proin nulla nibh, fermentum eu purus quis, hendrerit posuere arcu</p>
</div>
```